# How to sort the dates and time in android?

Tags: android

I need to know how to sort the dates and time and storing it in to SQ Lite .
Please give me an example or some link.

Comment: if you put date and time in sqlite, you can retrieve it in sorted order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is best to store dates as integers by taking date.getTime(). Sorting is then really easy and recreating the date is easily done from the integer by new Date(time).

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDER BY your_date DESC (or ASC) ;-)